# Laço "for" não percorre todos os itens da lista

Tags: javascript, array, for

Estou com um problema na seguinte função:

```
function limpaLista() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('resposta');
    var itens = document.getElementsByClassName('Repos');
    for (item of itens) {
        lista.removeChild(item);
    }
}
```

Ela deveria excluir totalmente uma lista de nomes, mas por algum motivo ela exclui metade da lista apenas a cada execução.

Comment: Coloca um console.log e verifica se a quantidade de itens e a lista realmente são os corretos, além disso, verifica se realmente todos os itens contém essa classe Repos.

Comment: segue o resultado:
```
function limpaLista() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('resposta');
    var itens = document.getElementsByClassName('Repos');
    console.log(itens.length);
    console.log(itens);
    for (item of itens) {
        lista.removeChild(item);
    }
    console.log(itens.length);
    console.log(itens);
}
```

Comment: Resolvido com a resposta abaixo, vlw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica não está errada, mas tem uma armadilha nesse código.

O retorno do método `getElementsByClassName` é um `HTMLCollection`, uma lista "viva" que é atualizada conforme você adiciona ou remove elementos no DOM. Ao remover esses elementos do DOM, você está removendo da sua lista também, e é preciso ter cuidado ao se iterar sobre uma lista que está sendo reduzida.

Minha sugestão é transformar esse `HTMLCollection` num array comum antes de remover os itens, assim, apesar dos elementos serem removidos do DOM, ao menos a estrutura da sua lista se mantém integra durante a iteração:

```
function limpaLista() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('resposta');
    var itens = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('Repos'));
    for (item of itens) {
        lista.removeChild(item);
    }
}
```

Ou alternativamente faça um `while` para remover todos os itens enquanto eles existirem:

```
function limpaLista() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('resposta');
    var itens = document.getElementsByClassName('Repos');
    while (itens.length) {
        lista.removeChild(itens[0]);
    }
}
```